# Golang Package Systemwide Installation

Tags: go, installation, package

Is it possible to install a Golang package system-wide and not need the source code afterwards in order to compile programs that use it?

More particularly, having just the pkg/linux_amd64_dynlink/ directory with, for example, libstringutil.so stringutil.a and stringutil.shlibname files, how can I compile a simple hello.go that imports stringutil?

Comment: do you mean as library?

Comment: this stack question might help [building-and-linking-dynamically-from-a-go-binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431296/building-and-linking-dynamically-from-a-go-binary)

Comment: it seems support is limited, on mac it gives following error `-buildmode=shared not supported on darwin/amd64`

Comment: tldr: no, and it is a good thing. Best thing is to create a service that does the generic things and call that.

Comment: Nobody has resolved this? I don't want those packages installed in my ~/go directory, I too want them system-wide so that it is available to other users in my Linux/Unix system.